# Kiel pluramemo iĝis populara en Esperantio?

Tags: culture, history

Mi multe aŭdis ke inter la parolantoj de la lingvo Esperanto ekzistas sufiĉe granda elcento de homoj, kiuj vivas en pluramemaj rilatoj.

Ekzemple, la anoj de tre konata muzikbando "La Perdita Generacio" estas pluramemaj. Mi mem parolis kun ili pri tio.

Ĉu la populareco de tiu filozofio ĉiam ekzistis en Esperantio? Se ne, kiel ĝi alvenis kaj kial ĝi populariĝis?

Comment: LPG ne estas la nuraj muzikistoj kiuj rilatas al pluramemo, Gijom' Armide eĉ verkis belan kanton pri la temo :) https://m.soundcloud.com/guillaume-armide/07-amu-rin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mi pensas ke ĉiuj kiuj spertis la eŭropan junularan Esperanto-movadon dum la lastaj dek jaroj povas atesti ke pluramemuloj abundas kaj sufiĉe malfermas. Kaj ke estas kreskanta tendenco.

Se nia muziko iel kulpas pri tio mi ne povas juĝi.

Mi mem pensas ke la plej grava klarigo estas la vezika strukturo de Esperantio. Oni aperas en unika aranĝo kun unika mikso da homoj kio neniam denove ekzistos. Tiam la bariloj esplori, pensi, agi en iom eksterkadra maniero iĝas malpli altaj. Homoj simple pli facile kuraĝas salti ;)

Answer (score 5):

La plej simpla klarigo estas ke Esperanto estas alternativa afero kaj sekve ĝi altiras homojn al kiuj plaĉas alternativaj ideoj - vegetaranismo, mondfederalismo, kaj eventuale pluramemo.

Answer (score 1):

Mi ne dubas, ke vi multe aŭdis pri relative granda nombro de pluramemuloj inter la Esperantistoj. Mi tre dubas, ke tio estas reale observebla kaj ekzistanta fenomeno.

Comment: Estus interese scii verajn nombrojn. Mi pripensis tion iomete skribante mian respondon. Finfine mi decidis ke mi simple ne scias kaj eble ne gravas. De mia persona sperto, mi konas en la tuta mondo unu malferme plurameman personon, kaj tiu estas Esperantisto. Tio ne estas granda nombro, sed gxi estas "relative" granda nombro.